# CodeIgniter: CRUD order_by error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having an error for CRUD methods. Can anyone please help me.

**JS_Model.php**

```
class JS_Model extends CI_Model
{

    protected $_table_name = '';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
    protected $_order_by = '';
    protected $_rules = array();
    protected $_timestamps = FALSE;


  function __construct()
  {
        parent::__construct();
  }

  public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE)
  {
        if($id != NULL) {

            $filter     =   $this->_primary_filter;
            $id         =   $filter($id);

            $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);            
            $method = 'row';

        } elseif($single == TRUE) {

            $method = 'row';

        } else {

            $method = 'result';

        }

        if(!count($this->db->ar_orderby)){
            $this->db->order_by($this->order_by);    
        }        

        return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
  }

  public function get_by($where, $single = FALSE)
  {
    $this->db->where($where);

        return $this->get(NULL, $single);
  }

}
```

**page_m.php**

```
class Page_m extends JS_Model
{

    protected $_table_name = 'pages';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
    protected $_order_by = 'order';
    protected $_rules = array();
    protected $_timestamps = FALSE;

}
```

**page.php**

```
class Page extends Frontend_Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('page_m');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $pages = $this->page_m->get();

        //var_dump($pages);
        print_r($pages);

    }
}
```

**Error messages are as below**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Page::$order_by

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 51
```

**and**

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '' in 'order clause'

SELECT * FROM (`pages`) ORDER BY `

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\my-cms\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Comment: try to replace  $this->db->order_by($this->order_by);     to  $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Message: Undefined property: Page::$order_by**

In this case use `_order_by` instead of `order_by` like this:

```
$this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
```

**Unknown column '' in 'order clause'**

This should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`pages`) ORDER BY `column_name`; //column_name was missing
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. However just wonder.. after set `$this->_order_by` other error also gone.. how?

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->order_by($this->order_by);
```

should be

```
 $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
```